# Probability question:k-jar problem

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability

Each of k jars contains m white and n black balls. A ball is randomly
chosen from jar 1 and transferred to jar 2, then a ball is randomly chosen from jar 2 and transferred to jar 3, etc. Finally, a ball is randomly chosen from jar k. Show that the probability that the last ball is white is the same as the probability that the first ball is white                         , i.e. , it is   m / ( m + n ) .

Could you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $A_j$ be the event that the $j$th ball transferred is white.

Claim: $P(A_j)=m/(m+n)$ for $j=1,2,\ldots$.

Proof by induction on $j$.  Clearly true for $j=1$.  Now assume true for $j=k-1$.  Then
\begin{align*}
P(A_k)&=P(A_{k-1})P(A_k\mid A_{k-1})+P(A_{k-1}^c)P(A_k\mid A_{k-1}^c)\\
&=\frac{m}{m+n}\,\frac{m+1}{m+n+1}+\frac{n}{m+n}\,\frac{m}{m+n+1}\\
&=\frac{m}{m+n}\bigg(\frac{m+1}{m+n+1}+\frac{n}{m+n+1}\bigg)\\
&=\frac{m}{m+n}.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

The expected proportion of white balls is constant in each jar throughout the entire operation.